# How do I establish these polynomial limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, polynomials, improper-integrals

I have the following task I cannot solve:

Let p be a polynomial of the form $p(x)= x^{n}+\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}x^{k}.$

Prove that:

i) $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}p(x)=+∞$

ii) $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}p(x)=+∞$ if n is even

iii) $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}p(x)=-∞$ if n is not even

Earlier I had to prove, that the following is true:

"Let $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$,
with $\lim{x\to\infty}x_{n}=+\infty$, and let $(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be
a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}y_{n}=0$.

Then: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{n}y_{n}=sign(c)*\infty$"

So I think we need to use it. Remember: I have already proven the theorem. It is very important for ii) and iii).

In general I do not know what I have to do now. I'm a little unsure how exactly the steps need to be. Would someone be kind enough to give tips or help me? I am very grateful for that.

Comment: **Hint :** $$x^{n}+\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}x^{k} = x^{n}\left(1+\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}x^{k-n} \right)$$

Comment: Just thought about it. Can I leave the Limes running for $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^{n}(1+\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}x^{k-n})$$. Then $$x^{n}$$ would be zero?

Comment: infinite* (My bad)

Comment: My approach is more primitive than that of @TheSilverDoe; unsurprising, since my experience is limited.  Let $~B = \max\{|a_0|, ~|a_1|, \cdots, |a_{n-1}|\}.~$ Focusing on values of $~x > 1,~$ this implies that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k x^k \geq (-1) \times n \times Bx^{n-1}.$$  This implies that $$p(x) \geq x^{n-1} ( ~x - nB ~).$$

Comment: The approach in my previous comment should cover each of parts (i), (ii), and (iii).

Comment: I solved it. The Hint of TheSilverDoe was useful. Up there we have a product. In general we only have to show that x^n is
improperly convergent. We know the sum converges to zero. It remains x^n*1. So we have a product where one factor is divergent and the other factor is limited. There is a theorem that says that this all is improperly convergent. In case ii) and iii) it's up to if n is even or not. Then you can use the theorem, that I just has  proven